# Add record type of an object for a flow

Tags: apex, workflow, flow

I am in a mid of a process implementation using flow. Unable to find selection of record type in a flow.

Kindly let me know id static list creating is the only option working

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following steps should solve your problem :

1. Create two variables in flow, name may be something like
       "SelectedRecordTypeName" and "SelectedRecordTypeId".
2. Now on Screen, create field of type "Dropdown List"
3. In choice setting, choose Dynamic Record choice
4. In "Create a choice for each" field choose "RecordType"
5. In condition section, choose "SObjectType"
   equals "your object name". For example, if you want to display
   record type of Accounts then choose Account on Value field.
6. Choice Label - Name
7. Choice stored value - Id
8. In Additional Options - assign Id and Name to variables declared above.

Now, on next screen you will have selected recordtypeId and Name in variable you choosed in step 8.

I have done something [like this in this blog post as well](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/creating-lookup-field-in-flow/), let me know if you are still facing any issue

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) do a Dynamic Record Lookup to return all of the "RecordType" object records that meet your object's criteria.  This would be for a Screen and a User to select the one they want.

2) you need to do a Lookup on the RecordType Object.  You can search on the Name of the RecordType so you can find the 'XYZ' Record Type you were looking for.  This is a good one if you're doing this dynamically based on a field or something on the new or existing Record.

Note - Flow isn't going to dynamically show only RecordTypes that people have access to create records with... to do something like that you're going to have a tough time.